# Reading a java properties file, values keep going to null

Tags: java, oop, null, testng, properties-file

I am trying to read in values from a java properties file so I can use them all throughout my tests. I have BaseTest which reads in the properties. When I print right after I read the values in BaseTest, the values show correctly. But when I try to access them in test1 which extends BaseTest, the values are null. I have a java class that accepts the values like a template, nothing initialized. The values are populated with the TestValuesReader class. How can I have the values persist all throughout the code/not be null?

```
 public class test1 extends BaseTest {
        String var1 = TestValues.VAR1;

        @Test
        public void someFunction() throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println(var1);
        }
}

public class BaseTest{

    public void readValues() throws IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("TestValues.properties");
        p.load(is);
        TestValuesReader valuesReader = new TestValuesReader();
        valuesReader.readStrings(p);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        readValues();
        System.out.println(TestValues.VAR1); //this will give back the correct value, but when called
        //in someFunction() it is null
    }
}

public class TestValues{
    public static String VAR1; //not initialized, supposed to be ready from properties file
}

public class TestValuesReader {
    public void readStrings(Properties p) {
          TestValues.VAR1 = p.getProperty("VAR1");
    }
}




FAILED: checkForCandidate
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:97)
    at com.iai.test.pages.SpatialQuery.setAimPointInput(SpatialQuery.java:50)
    at com.iai.test.tests.cgm.CG_AX_001.checkForCandidate(CG_AX_001.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: You should close streams after reading with `InputStream.close();` or a `try-with-resource`. But this is not answering your question. Do you get a Stacktrace?

Comment: @LinuxServer i added a stack trace but it tells me what i already know which is that my test is trying to send keyboard input to some web object but the value is null. I think the error has to do with the fact that the values are not persisting after we exit whatever happens in BaseTest and move on to test1

Comment: I cant help you without a stacktrace.

Comment: @LinuxServer stack trace has been added under the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [Static Initialization Block or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to invoke `super.readValues()`. Do it as follows:

## Using a Static Initialization Block:

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {
    String var1;

    {
        try {
            super.readValues();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        var1 = TestValues.VAR1;
    }

    @Test
    public void someFunction() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(var1);
    }
}
```

## Using a Constructor:

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {
    String var1;

    Test1() {
        try {
            super.readValues();
            var1 = TestValues.VAR1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void someFunction() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(var1);
    }
}
```

I've tested both the solutions to be working as expected.

**Additional notes:**

1. Make sure you have some value against the key, `VAR1` e.g. `VAR1=x` in the properties file.
2. I also suggest you follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `class test1` should be `class Test1` as per the naming conventions.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there any way to do it the way I was attempting and to have all the values assigned to the TestValues class separately, then just call them after assignment in a different class?

Comment: You are most welcome. This is the recommended way to do it. Depending on how you design other classes, there can be different ways to call `readValues()` but that is your key function to be invoked.